# Android Studio automatically adds the already existing Kotlin plugin and appcompat component when create a new Activity

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I switch to the Gradle Version Catalog, and version is gradle-7.4.1-bin, I have added all my dependencies to the libs.versions.toml file in the Gradle folder in the root of the project.
This is my build.gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.application) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.library) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.hilt) apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

But when i create a new Activity, build.gradle file will automatically add a line of

```
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
```

The build.gradle file in the app folder will also automatically add the dependencies like

```
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
```

I've already added all these dependencies and they compile fine, how do I stop them from being added automatically when I create a new Activity, am I doing it the wrong way?

android studio version:
Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 2